# Elastic search update multiple fields in single query request

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

working on ES 5.x version, and need to update multiple fields update using script.Also share , have any better solution .

```
POST ../100/_update
    {
    "script" : {
        "inline": "ctx._source.student.hobbies.add(params.tag)",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params" : {
            "tag" : "cricket"
        }
    }
}
```

also the same student i need to update phone no. now i am calling 2 api for update hobbies and phone number. looking for better solution to update both in single query

Comment: Just add a semicolon after the first statement and add a second statement ;-)

Comment: `{
    "script" : {
        "inline": "ctx._source.student.hobbies.add(params.tag)",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params" : {
            "tag" : "cricket"
        }
    }
}
------
{
    "script" : {
        "inline": "ctx._source.student.phone.add(params.tag)",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params" : {
            "tag" : "122-33-4567"
        }
    }
} `  - where to add semicolon

Comment: `{
    "script" : {
        "inline": "ctx._source.student.hobbies.add(params.tag)",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params" : {
            "tag" : "cricket"
        }
    }
};
{
    "script" : {
        "inline": "ctx._source.student.phone.add(params.tag)",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params" : {
            "tag" : "122-33-4567"
        }
    }
}` - i tried this . The first script hobbies got updated. but not phone number.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just add a semicolon between both statements, like this:

```
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.student.hobbies.add(params.hobby); ctx._source.student.phone.add(params.phone)",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "hobby": "cricket",
      "phone" : "122-33-4567"
    }
  }
}
```

If you have more than one value to add to an array, you can do it like this

```
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.student.hobbies.addAll(params.hobbies); ctx._source.student.phone.add(params.phone)",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "hobbies": ["football", "cricket"],
      "phone" : "122-33-4567"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But i couldn't add more hobbies. here hobbies field type is array.. if add "cricket,football" then it will treat as single value and stored as "cricket,football", but i am excepting "cricket" , "football"